# Can't attach EC2 instance to Network Interface

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

When trying to attach a network interface, it says...

> No instances were found for this availability zone.

My instance is in **us-east-1c** and my network interface is in **us-east-1b**. Is that significant?

If so, how do I create the VPC in the same zone and if not then why this error?

**EDIT:**

I've re-created the VPC and the Network Interface is now **us-east-1c** and the EC2 instance is also **us-east-1c**. Same error message though!

Comment: are the interface and the instance in the same VPC? They must be.

Comment: did you try putting everything in the same VPC yet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The subnet you are trying to connect to must be in the same availability zone as the instance. When you go to create a VPC, you usually create it with one subnet. Click "edit public subnet" and then select an availability zone. For example I see us-east-1a, us-east-1c, and us-east-1d. By default it is "no preference", which I believe means it will choose one for you.

Alternatively you can add a new subnet to your VPC. You can set an availability zone for a subnet in the same manner as above.

Just to be clear - us-east-1c and us-east-1b are distinctly different availability zones.

Also, see the [VPC FAQ](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/faqs/#ENI1)

Q. Can I attach a network interface in one AZ to an instance in another AZ?
Network interfaces can only be attached to instances residing in the same AZ.

Q. Can I attach a network interface in one VPC to an instance in another VPC?
Network interfaces can only be attached to instances in the same VPC as the interface.

Comment: I've updated the question.